# Get Database Table Name from Entity Framework MetaData

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-metadata

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the underlying SQL table name for a given entity type. I've experimented around with the MetadataWorkspace queries and while I can get lots of information from the object or the storage space, I can't seem to figure out how to map between the two.

So say I have a type in the object model called Lookup - how do I find the tablename (wws_lookups) in the database?

I can query all the EntityType objects for CSpace and SSpace and I can see both listed correctly but I can't figure out how to get SSpace from CSpace.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Follow answer at different place:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27216884/819843

Answer (score 44):

I use Nigel's approach (extracting table name from `.ToTraceString()`) but with some modifications, because his code won't work if the table is not in the default SQL Server schema (`dbo.{table-name}`).

I've created extension methods for `DbContext` and `ObjectContext` objects:

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext;

        return objectContext.GetTableName<T>();
    }

    public static string GetTableName<T>(this ObjectContext context) where T : class
    {
        string sql = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToTraceString();
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"FROM\s+(?<table>.+)\s+AS");
        Match match = regex.Match(sql);

        string table = match.Groups["table"].Value;
        return table;
    }
}
```

More details here:
[Entity Framework: Get mapped table name from an entity](https://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/entity-framework-get-mapped-table-name-from-an-entity/)

Comment: Your answer returns an empty string when I try it. And the regex supplied by @Dabblernl causes an error :`parsing "FROM\s+[?(?<table>[A-Za-z0-9]*)]?\s+AS" - Too many )'s`.  My sql looks like this `SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text]
    FROM [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent1]`

Comment: Substituting `int startIndex = sql.IndexOf("FROM ") + 5;
 int endIndex = sql.IndexOf(" AS", startIndex);
 return sql.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);` for the Regex gets me `[dbo].[Questions]` - which suits my purposes

Comment: But the method fails if you pass it a derived type: `There are no EntitySets defined for the specified entity type 'Models.ReplacementCost'. If 'Models.ReplacementCost' is a derived type, use the base type instead`

Comment: @Colin: you're right, at the moment is not working if you have the following format: `schema.table`. I will try to fix the regex ASAP

Comment: @Colin: Fixed the regex to include the schema. Regarding derived types - I'm afraid I can't help you with that particular problem :(

Comment: @RuiJarimba What about this please: string s=typeof(T).ToString(); return s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);

Comment: @LeiYang: Not a good idea IMO, because the type name may not match the table name. Also, it doesn't have in consideration the table schema e.g. `dbo.Foo`

Comment: Nice solution, but won't work for derived types. It throws an error telling you to use the base type instead, which wont help. I extended the dbset for it using your solution
`public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
        {
            string sql = dbSet.ToString();
            Regex regex = new Regex("FROM (?<table>.*) AS");
            Match match = regex.Match(sql);

            string table = match.Groups["table"].Value;
            return table;
        }`

Comment: Hi @SeanMissingham, keep in  mind that my answer is 5 years old :-) I'd suggest you to post your solution as a new answer, it might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 31):

**EDIT**
This answer now obsolete due to new feature in EF 6.1 : [mapping between table types](http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/). **Go there first!**

I had a problem with the other answers because I have a derived type. I got this method (inside my context class) to work - I have only one layer of inheritance in my model at the moment

```
private readonly static Dictionary<Type, EntitySetBase> _mappingCache 
       = new Dictionary<Type, EntitySetBase>();

private EntitySetBase GetEntitySet(Type type)
{
    //If it's a proxy, get the entity type associated with it
    type = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(type);

    if (_mappingCache.ContainsKey(type))
        return _mappingCache[type];

    string baseTypeName = type.BaseType.Name;
    string typeName = type.Name;

    ObjectContext octx = _ObjectContext;
    var es = octx.MetadataWorkspace
                    .GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
                    .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
                    .SelectMany(c => c.BaseEntitySets
                                    .Where(e => e.Name == typeName 
                                    || e.Name == baseTypeName))
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    if (es == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Entity type not found in GetEntitySet", typeName);

    // Put es in cache.
    _mappingCache.Add(type, es);

    return es;
}

internal String GetTableName(Type type)
{
    EntitySetBase es = GetEntitySet(type);

    //if you are using EF6
    return String.Format("[{0}].[{1}]", es.Schema, es.Table);

    //if you have a version prior to EF6
    //return string.Format( "[{0}].[{1}]", 
    //        es.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value, 
    //        es.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value );
}

internal Type GetObjectType(Type type)
{
    return System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectType(type);
}
```

NB There are plans to [improve the Metadata API](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1471) and if this isn't getting what we want then we can look at [EF Code First Mapping Between Types & Tables](http://romiller.com/2013/09/24/ef-code-first-mapping-between-types-tables/)

Comment: I independently stumbled upon this after reading many answers like Alex James' to the various permutations of this question all over the web.  Is it just that they can't get past the "mapping" to see that the only requirement is table name? Or is there some deep flaw or limitation that makes this code unworkable in a way that it should be considered "incorrect"?  At any rate this corroborates my answer, thanks Colin.

Comment: I can't see the Schema and Table properties

Comment: @AlanMacdonald Sorry, I hadn't realised they were only available in EF6 https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Metadata/Edm/EntitySetBase.cs

Comment: @AlanMacdonald Wiktor Zychla picked up my code and altered it to use a cache. It looks like his version will work on EF5 but he's removed the check for BaseType.Name so perhaps you can use a combination of the 2. http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html

Comment: @AlanMacdonald see my edit. Now incorporates Wiktor's caching

Comment: I think this only works when the name of the table is the same as the entity name. What if you map "User" entity to "T_User" table?

Comment: @Jowen no it works in that case too. Have you tested it?

Comment: I'm missing the method GetObjectType(type)?!

Comment: I used romiller's method (from the link) and it worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 10):

Adding another answer for the special case when you use **annotations** to explicitly tell EF which table name to use. For example, if you have:

```
[Table("tblCompany")]
public class Company
{
}
```

You can easily access the `TableAttribute` annotation to find the table name:

```
((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute)typeof(YourNamespace.BO.Company).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute))).Name
```

which is `tblCompany` for the given sample.

As ready-to-use method:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public static string GetTableName<T>() {
    return ((TableAttribute)typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TableAttribute))).Name;
}
```

(I am aware that this will not help the OP but given the title of the question, people may end up here who may be looking for this answer.)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 9):

Most of the answers here don't work with derived classes. This one does. And gives you the schema too. I combined the answers [here](http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/) and improved on it a little (by taking out things like First() and Single() and converting them to things like Where() and SelectMany() and returning the schema name).

This works with EF 6.1+

```
// This can return multiple values because it is possible to have one entity correspond to multiple tables when doing entity splitting.
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        // Get the part of the model that contains info about the actual CLR types
        var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

        // Get the entity type from the model that maps to the CLR type
        var entityType = metadata
                .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == type);

        // Get the entity set that uses this entity type
        var entitySet = metadata.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace).Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).Cast<EntityType>().Single(x => x.Name == entityType.Name);

        // Find the mapping between conceptual and storage model for this entity set
        var entitySetMappings = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace).Single().EntitySetMappings.ToList();

        // Find the storage entity sets (tables) that the entity is mapped
        //EntitySet table;

        var fragments = new List<MappingFragment>();

        var mappings = entitySetMappings.Where(x => x.EntitySet.Name == entitySet.Name);

        //if (mappings.Count() > 0)
        //return mappings.SelectMany(m => m.EntityTypeMappings.SelectMany(em => em.Fragments)).ToList();

        fragments.AddRange(mappings.SelectMany(m => m.EntityTypeMappings.SelectMany(em => em.Fragments)));

        fragments.AddRange(entitySetMappings.Where(x => x.EntityTypeMappings.Where(y => y.EntityType != null).Any(y => y.EntityType.Name == entitySet.Name))
            .SelectMany(m => m.EntityTypeMappings.Where(x => x.EntityType != null && x.EntityType.Name == entityType.Name).SelectMany(x => x.Fragments)));

        //if (mapping != null)
        //return mapping.EntityTypeMappings.Where(x => x.EntityType != null).Single(x => x.EntityType.Name == entityType.Name).Fragments;

        fragments.AddRange(entitySetMappings.Where(x => x.EntityTypeMappings.Any(y => y.IsOfEntityTypes.Any(z => z.Name == entitySet.Name)))
        .SelectMany(m => m.EntityTypeMappings.Where(x => x.IsOfEntityTypes.Any(y => y.Name == entitySet.Name)).SelectMany(x => x.Fragments)));

        //var fragments = getFragments();

        // Return the table name from the storage entity set

        var tableNames = fragments.Select(f =>
        {
            var schemaName = f.StoreEntitySet.Schema;
            var tableName = (string)f.StoreEntitySet.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value ?? f.StoreEntitySet.Name;
            var name = $"[{schemaName}].[{tableName}]";
            return name;
        }).Distinct().ToList();

        return tableNames;
    }
```

Comment: That's monstruous in terms of length and complexity just to get a table schema and name, but against most of answers here I should admit that for my EDMX in EF6 it WORKS PERFECTLY. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In [entity-framework-core](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) versions 3.0 and 3.1 it's rather [trivial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.gettablename?view=efcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to):

```
var myClassTableName = _context.Model
  .FindEntityType(typeof(MyClass)).GetTableName();
```

Answer (score 6):

No, unfortunately it is impossible using the Metadata APIs to get to the tablename for a given entity.

This is because the Mapping metadata is not public, so there is no way to go from C-Space to S-Space using the EF's APIs.

If you *really* need to do this you could always build the map yourself by parsing the MSL. This is not for the faint of heart, but it should be possible, unless you are using [QueryViews](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2008/12/19/definingquery-versus-queryview.aspx) (which are incredibly rare), at which point it is for all intents and purposes impossible (you would have to parse ESQL... argh!)

Alex James

Microsoft.

Comment: This seems a really silly limitation given that you can in fact browser the storage data. Bummer. Thanks Alex.

Comment: Is this answer still valid for newer versions of Entity Framework ?

Comment: ran today against that limitation really silly business decision!

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing codefirst in EF6, you can just add something like the following to your dbcontext class.

```cs
    public string GetTableName(Type entityType)
    {
        var sql = Set(entityType).ToString();
        var regex = new Regex(@"FROM \[dbo\]\.\[(?<table>.*)\] AS");
        var match = regex.Match(sql);

        return match.Groups["table"].Value;
    }
```

Comment: This is perhaps the most elegant and simple solution I've seen. I wish I could upvote more.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to delete data using EF without having to load it first I described it in a little more detain in: http://nigelfindlater.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-delete-objects-in-ef4-without.html

The trick is to cast the IQueriable into an ObjectQuery and use the ToTraceString method. Then edit the resulting sql string. It works but you need to be careful because you are bypassing the the mechanisms that EF has in place for maintaining dependancies and contraints. But for performance reasons I think it's ok to do this....

have fun...

Nigel...

```
    private string GetClause<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> clause) where TEntity : class 
    { 
        string snippet = "FROM [dbo].["; 

        string sql = ((ObjectQuery<TEntity>)clause).ToTraceString(); 
        string sqlFirstPart = sql.Substring(sql.IndexOf(snippet)); 

        sqlFirstPart = sqlFirstPart.Replace("AS [Extent1]", ""); 
        sqlFirstPart = sqlFirstPart.Replace("[Extent1].", ""); 

        return sqlFirstPart; 
    } 

   public void DeleteAll<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> clause) where TEntity : class 
    { 
        string sqlClause = GetClause<TEntity>(clause); 
        this.context.ExecuteStoreCommand(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "DELETE {0}", sqlClause)); 
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution in LinqPad, but where do you get `ObjectQuery` from? Is that coming from a NUGET package? In the link you provided I couldn't find any hint regarding that. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the T4 template for POCO classes you can get it by altering the T4 Template. See snippet:

```
<#  
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
region.Begin("Custom Properties");

string xPath = "//*[@TypeName='" + entity.FullName + "']";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(inputFile);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx");

XmlNode item;
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
item = root.SelectSingleNode(xPath);

#>
    //<#= xPath #>
    //<#= entity.FullName #>
    //<#= (item == null).ToString() #>

<# if (item != null) #>
// Table Name from database
public string TableName { get { return "<#= item.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["StoreEntitySet"].Value #>"; } }
<#

region.End();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 4):

Using EF Core with SQL server it's as easy as:

```
_context.Model.FindEntityType(YOUR_VAR_TYPE).SqlServer().TableName
```

Comment: Postgres using Npgsql 
_context.Model.FindEntityType(YOUR_VAR_TYPE).Npgsql().TableName

Package: (Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround (not great, but neither are the alternatives...):

```
var sql = Context.EntitySetName.ToTraceString();
```

...then parse the SQL, which should be quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I was able to come up with using LINQ to XML. The code gets the mappings for column names as well.

```
var d = XDocument.Load("MyModel.edmx");
XNamespace n = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs";
var l = (from etm in d.Descendants()
            where etm.Name == n + "EntityTypeMapping"
            let s = etm.Attribute("TypeName").Value
            select new
            {
                Name = s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf(".") + 1).Replace(")", ""),
                Table = etm.Element(n + "MappingFragment").Attribute("StoreEntitySet").Value,
                Properties = (from sp in etm.Descendants(n + "ScalarProperty")
                            select new
                            {
                                Name = sp.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                Column = sp.Attribute("ColumnName").Value
                            }).ToArray()
            }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use the StoreItemCollection from the Metadata.  This guy has already provided an example of using it:  [Get Tables and Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493299/get-tables-and-relationships)

Answer (score 3):

EF 6.1, code-first:

```
public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    return objectContext.GetTableName(typeof(T));
}

public static string GetTableName(this DbContext context, Type t)
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    return objectContext.GetTableName(t);
}

private static readonly Dictionary<Type,string> TableNames = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

public static string GetTableName(this ObjectContext context, Type t)
    {
        string result;

        if (!TableNames.TryGetValue(t, out result))
        {
            lock (TableNames)
            {
                if (!TableNames.TryGetValue(t, out result))
                {

                    string entityName = t.Name;

                    ReadOnlyCollection<EntityContainerMapping> storageMetadata = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace);

                    foreach (EntityContainerMapping ecm in storageMetadata)
                    {
                        EntitySet entitySet;
                        if (ecm.StoreEntityContainer.TryGetEntitySetByName(entityName, true, out entitySet))
                        {
                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entitySet.Schema))
                            {
                                result = entitySet.Table;
                                break;
                            }


                            //we must recognize if we are under SQL Server Compact version, which does not support multiple schemas
                            //SQL server compact does not support schemas, entity framework sets entitySet.Schema set to "dbo", anyway
                            //the System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker.GetTableName() returns only table name
                            //schema is (not) added by the overrides of the method AnyModelTableExistsInDatabase
                            //the SqlCeTableExistenceChecker has the knowledge that there is no metadata schema needed
                            //the SqlTableExistenceChecker has the knowledge that there is metadata with schema, which should be added to the table names

                            var entityConnection = (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection) context.Connection;

                            DbConnection storeConnection = entityConnection.StoreConnection;

                            if (storeConnection != null && "SqlCeConnection".Equals(storeConnection.GetType().Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                result = entitySet.Table;
                                break;
                            }

                            result = entitySet.Schema  + "." + entitySet.Table;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    TableNames.Add(t,result);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not [repeat anwers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27216884/861716). If two questions can be answered by exactly the same answer, you should mark one of them as duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, you need more rep for that, but AFAIK you can always flag a question for moderator attention. Leaving a link to the other answer (as you did) is a good alternative. It may trigger other users to mark the duplicate. SO is just a bit wary of repeated content, because it may cause diversion (anyone can edit any answer...).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to find the table name. It is a bit odd but works.
VB:

```
For Each Table In northwind.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(New System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace)
        'adds table name to a list of strings all table names in EF have the project namespace in front of it.'
        If Table.ToString.Contains("namespace of project") then
            'using substring to remove project namespace from the table name.'
            TableNames.Add(Table.ToString.Substring("length of namespace name"))      
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try MappingAPI extension: https://efmappingapi.codeplex.com/

It is really easy to use

```
context.Db<YourEntityType>().TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version assuming you have context and have a selected entity in memory that you need to find the real table name for.

```
    
    public static class ObjectContextExtentions
    {
        public static string TableNameFor(this ObjectContext context, ObjectStateEntry entry)
        {
            var generic =
                context.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().First(p => p.Name == entry.EntityKey.EntitySetName);
            var objectset = generic.GetValue(context, null);

            var method = objectset.GetType().GetMethod("ToTraceString");
            var sql = (String)method.Invoke(objectset, null);

            var match = Regex.Match(sql, @"FROM\s+\[dbo\]\.\[(?<TableName>[^\]]+)\]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                return match.Groups["TableName"].Value;
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to find Table name.");
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using EF5 and a litle bit o reflection, something like the following should do the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EFHelpers {
    public class EFMetadataMappingHelper {
        public static string GetTableName(MetadataWorkspace metadata, DbEntityEntry entry) {
            var entityType = entry.Entity.GetType();

            var objectType = getObjectType(metadata, entityType);
            var conceptualSet = getConceptualSet(metadata, objectType);
            var storeSet = getStoreSet(metadata, conceptualSet);
            var tableName = findTableName(storeSet);

            return tableName;
        }

        private static EntitySet getStoreSet(MetadataWorkspace metadata, EntitySetBase entitySet) {
            var csSpace = metadata.GetItems(DataSpace.CSSpace).Single();
            var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var entitySetMaps = (ICollection)csSpace.GetType().GetProperty("EntitySetMaps", flags).GetValue(csSpace, null);

            object mapping = null;

            foreach (var map in entitySetMaps) {
                var set = map.GetType().GetProperty("Set", flags).GetValue(map, null);
                if (entitySet == set) {
                    mapping = map;
                    break;
                }
            }

            var m_typeMappings = ((ICollection)mapping.GetType().BaseType.GetField("m_typeMappings", flags).GetValue(mapping)).OfType<object>().Single();
            var m_fragments = ((ICollection)m_typeMappings.GetType().BaseType.GetField("m_fragments", flags).GetValue(m_typeMappings)).OfType<object>().Single();
            var storeSet = (EntitySet) m_fragments.GetType().GetProperty("TableSet", flags).GetValue(m_fragments, null);

            return storeSet;
        }

        private static string findTableName(EntitySet storeSet) {
            string tableName = null;

            MetadataProperty tableProperty;

            storeSet.MetadataProperties.TryGetValue("Table", true, out tableProperty);
            if (tableProperty == null || tableProperty.Value == null)
                storeSet.MetadataProperties.TryGetValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator:Table", true, out tableProperty);

            if (tableProperty != null)
                tableName = tableProperty.Value as string;

            if (tableName == null)
                tableName = storeSet.Name;

            return tableName;
        }

        private static EntityType getObjectType(MetadataWorkspace metadata, Type entityType) {                
            var objectItemCollection = (ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace);

            var edmEntityType = metadata
                .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                .First(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == entityType);

            return edmEntityType;
        }

        private static EntitySetBase getConceptualSet(MetadataWorkspace metadata, EntityType entityType) {
            var entitySetBase = metadata
                .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
                .SelectMany(a => a.BaseEntitySets)
                .Where(s => s.ElementType.Name == entityType.Name)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return entitySetBase;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it is like this:

```
public string GetTableName(DbContext db, DbEntityEntry entry) {
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    return EFMetadataMappingHelper.GetTableName(metadata, entry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've been through the same problem, and I've produced an abstract code snippet which gives you two `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`($table_name,$columns_name_list).
First one has database Table + column name list, second one has local EF Entities + properties

Of course you can add more checks against data type, btw imho that would force you to write insanely complicated code.

P&L

P.S. Sorry for the compressed style, I'm a lambda fanatic

```
using (EFModelContext efmc = new EFModelContext("appConfigConnectionName"))
{
    string schemaName = "dbo";
    string sql = @"select o.name + '.' + c.name
               from sys.all_objects o 
                inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
                inner join sys.all_columns c on c.object_id = o.object_id
               where Rtrim(Ltrim(o.type)) in ('U') and s.name = @p0";

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> dbTableColumns = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    efmc.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sql, schemaName).Select(tc =>
    {
        string[] splitted = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(tc, "[.]");
        return new { TableName = splitted[0], ColumnName = splitted[1] };
    }).GroupBy(k => k.TableName, k => k.ColumnName).ToList().ForEach(ig => dbTableColumns.Add(ig.Key, ig.ToList()));

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> efTableColumns = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    efTableColumns = ((IObjectContextAdapter)uc).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace
                 .GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).OfType<EntityType>()
                 .ToDictionary( eft => eft.MetadataProperties
                                     .First(mp => mp.Name == "TableName").Value.ToString(),
                                eft => eft.Properties.Select(p => p.Name).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of using Entity Framework Core 2.0+, you can easily get the relational metadata using provided APIs.

```
foreach (var entityType in dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var tableName = entityType.Relational().TableName;
    foreach (var propertyType in entityType.GetProperties())
    {
        var columnName = propertyType.Relational().ColumnName;
    }
}
```

You need to have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational Nuget package installed to be able to use *Relational()* method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a quick and dirty way to get the table name (and you don't need it in your application's code), you can look at the XML generated for your Model.edmx. Find your entity in the  edmx:Mappings section and the line: MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="YourTableName" will give you the table's actual name.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right - this is a sad limitation in the Metadata API. I have to just load the MSL as an XML document and do lookups of S-space entities as I process my C-space model.

Answer (score 0):

For EF6, mixing/compressing code from other answers here and around (VB, I'm sorry):

```
    Public Function getDBTableName(data As myDataModel, ByVal entity As Object) As String
        Dim context = CType(data, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        Dim sName As String = entity.GetType.BaseType.Name 'use BaseType to avoid proxy names'
        Dim map = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(Of EntityContainerMapping)(DataSpace.CSSpace).FirstOrDefault

        Return (From esmap In map.EntitySetMappings 
                Select esmap.EntityTypeMappings.First(
                    Function(etm) 
                     etm.EntityType.Name = sName
                   ).Fragments.First.StoreEntitySet.Name).FirstOrDefault
        'TODO: use less .first everywhere but filter the correct ones'
    End Function
```

It works for db-first.
Relatively easy to understand following an .edmx file.

Answer (score 0):

Copying my answer to another question here.

If anyone is still looking, Here's how I did it. This is an extension method for the DBContext that takes a type and returns physical column names and their properties.

This utilizes object context to get physical columns list, then uses the "PreferredName" metadata property to map each column it its property.

Since it uses object context, it initiates a database connection, so the first run will be slow depending on the complexity of the context.

```
public static IDictionary<String, PropertyInfo> GetTableColumns(this DbContext ctx, Type entityType)
{
    ObjectContext octx = (ctx as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    EntityType storageEntityType = octx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
        .Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).OfType<EntityType>()
        .Single(x => x.Name == entityType.Name);

    var columnNames = storageEntityType.Properties.ToDictionary(x => x.Name,
        y => y.MetadataProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PreferredName")?.Value as string ?? y.Name);

    return storageEntityType.Properties.Select((elm, index) =>
            new {elm.Name, Property = entityType.GetProperty(columnNames[elm.Name])})
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Property);
}
```

To use it, just create a helper static class, and add above function; then it's as simple as calling

```
var tabCols = context.GetTableColumns(typeof(EntityType));
```

Comment: The question was about how to get table name, not columns. Additionnally, I've extracted the beginning of you code (until ".Single") and apparently it does not work if entity type name is different than table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension method to get Table name from your entity class
In this case, You wont need `DbContext` to get table name , it gets it inside extension method

```
public static string GetTableName<T>(this T entity) where T : class
{
    var object_context = GetObjectContext(entity);

    if (object_context == null || object_context.TransactionHandler == null)
        return null;

     var dbcontext=object_context.TransactionHandler.DbContext;
    var query= dbcontext.Set(entity.GetType()).ToString();
    var reg = new Regex(@"FROM \[dbo\]\.\[(?<table>.*)\] AS");
    var match = reg.Match(query);

    var tableName= match.Groups["table"].Value;
    return tableName;
}

private static ObjectContext GetObjectContext(object entity)
{
    var field = entity.GetType().GetField("_entityWrapper");

    if (field == null)
        return null;

    var val= field.GetValue(entity);
    var property = val.GetType().GetProperty("Context");
    var context = (ObjectContext)property.GetValue(val, null);

    return context;
}
```

This is where we reach to `DbContext`:

```
var object_context = GetObjectContext(entity)
```

Usage:

```
var tableName = entity.GetTableName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Model classes with `[Table("table_name")]` annotation, you can use this. If a type has no `[Table]` annotation it returns the name of a class, since it is it by default.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

...

private string GetTableName(Type type)
{
    if (Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(TableAttribute)))
    {
        var attr = (TableAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(TableAttribute));
        return attr.Name;
    }
    else return type.Name;
}
```