# How can I map database table and field names back into their EF Entity object and property names?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, mapping

I have a database table which records all **field changes** in all database tables which are mapped to **Entity Framework** Entities (via SQL Server **triggers**).

I am building a service which **outputs** these field changes to the client.

However, the client needs the **EF-Entity object and property names** and not the **database table and field names**.

For example, if these **database fields** change:

```
Table         Field        WhenChanged
------------  ------------ ----------          ...
Calendar      Event        2010-01-05 15:00:00
Calendar      Place        2010-01-05 15:22:00
```

I need to report that these **entity properties** changed:

```
Entity        Property        WhenChanged
------------  ------------ ----------              ...
Appointment   EventName        2010-01-05 15:00:00
Appointment   Place            2010-01-05 15:00:00
```

Some names are the same, some are not: the **mapping** is defined the **.edmx** file.

**Are there any EF methods I can call or tools I could use which would do this backward tablename-to-objectname and fieldname-to-propertyname translation without actually instantiating the objects?**

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate. There's a good answer here from Alex James: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895455/get-database-table-name-from-entity-framework-metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say ahead of time I don't know much about the Entity Framework. However based on experience with other ORMs not sure what you want will work since you are dealing with the physical data not a mapping per se.  So based on your example what you could do to solve your problem is have an entity that is mapped to your log file.  Then when you send this log file down have it contain a lookup (dictionary) or use reflection to determine what goes where and then send that change down.

If you are just looking to do a name switch as in you just want to provide a running log of changes you could use the concept of a MetaData table that contains your entity / property mappings to table / field names.  Then your sql could join to that table and pull back the associated name vs the database value.

Along the lines of the association / metadata route if you can parse your .edmx file you may be able to use that as your meta store and then just overlay the incoming values from the db based on that lookup.