# Get Tables and Relationships

Tags: .net, entity-framework, edmx

Is there a way to get a list of tables and relationships from an EDMX using the MetadataLoader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
MetadataWorkspace metadataWorkspace = null;
bool allMetadataLoaded =  loader.TryLoadAllMetadata(inputFile, out metadataWorkspace);
StoreItemCollection itemCollection = (StoreItemCollection)metadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace);

// Tables
foreach (var entity in itemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>())
{
    ...
}

// Relations
foreach (var association in itemCollection.GetItems<AssociationType>())
{
    ...
}
```