# How to get the TableName a particular entity property is mapped to

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity properties can be split across different tables, meaning that a single Entity can have it's columns mapped to different tables. How does one then, in code, retrieve the info on the particular table an entity property is mapped to.

```
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in typeof(DbContext).GetProperties())
            {
                if(pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.Name.Contains("DbSet"))
                {
                    var t = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
                    var tables = t.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<TableAttribute>();
                    foreach (var entityProperty in t.GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (entityProperty.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().Any<RequiredAttribute>())
                        {
                            var fieldname = entity.Name;

                             //I need to match this column with the table it belongs to here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So far, I have the code below to get at the entity property, from the object itself, how do I determine the particular table the current property is mapped to, in my database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9760774/1844389  or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6463557/1844389 or this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505974/1844389

Comment: Not really. I need to match each column/Field in my Entity to the table it belongs to so I can execute a query against the correct table for the particular field.

Comment: Isn't the ORM meant for querying the database?

Comment: This is at point of db object initialization. I want to add some constraints to database tables as they are created.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614941/unique-keys-in-entity-framework-4/16496291#16496291

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the OR/M for the actual generation of the SQL you actually need.

```
var dbContext = new DbContext();
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
var set = objectContext.Set<Foo>();
var query = from x in set
            where {stuff}
            select new { x.Bar, x.Baz ...};
var objectQuery = (ObjectQuery)query;
var command = objectQuery.CommandText;
var parameters = objectQuery.Parameters;
```