# Cast ITable to IEnuerable<object> - Dynamic LINQ to SQL Query with no DataTable information

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I need to write dynamic LINQ where I know nothing about the input table - data provider (which is why I'm using LINQ to SQL), no table name, nothing.  I want to be able to query the data given user-selected fields and given values, something like the following:

Having a `String` `TheTableName`,  and `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` `TheContext`:

```
    IEnumerable<object> GetQuery(List<string> theWhereFields, List<string> theWhereValues)
    {
        // for doing dynamically ala http://stackoverflow.com/a/25859319/3661120            

        var baseTable = (ITable)TheContext.GetType()
                            .GetProperty(TheTableName).GetValue(TheContext, null); // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1924966/3661120                       

        IEnumerable<object> query = (IEnumerable<object>) baseTable;
        for (int i = 0; i < theWhereFields.Count; i++)
        {
            var whereField = theWhereFields[i];
            var whereValue = theWhereValues[i];
            query = query.Where(whereField + "=" + whereValue);  // possible due to System.Linq.Dynamic
        }

        return query;            
    }
```

Is it correct to cast the `ITable` to an `IEnumerable<object>` as I've done here?

Note `ITable` is from `System.Data.Linq`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what is `ITable`?

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable(v=vs.110).aspx.  It is IQueryable, but not necessarily IEnumerable.

Comment: TheContext is the DataSet so how do you know which table you want?

Comment: Sorry, also have a string `TheTableName`.  Will edit to reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

NO.

**Long Answer**

`ITable` has this signature:

```
public interface ITable : IQueryable, IEnumerable
```

If you have an instance of a type which implements that, like below:

```
public class MyTable : System.Data.Linq.ITable
{
    // Implementation ...
}
```

And you do this:

```
var myTable = new MyTable();
var iterator = myTable as IEnumerable<Object>;
```

It will return null because `MyTable` implements `ITable` and both of them do not implement `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

However, this will work:

```
var iterator = myTable as IEnumerable; // or IQueryable
```

So depending on what you mean by `Is it correct to cast the ITable to an IEnumerable<object> as I've done here`. It will not throw exception, but it will never result in anything until you use it and it will blow up with a null reference exception on this line:

```
query = query.Where(whereField + "=" + whereValue);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I guess I will just use `IQueryable`.