# How to get table name from DbContext at runtime

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to get the database table name from **DbContext** at runtime, I found [posts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/a851c5a6-807e-40f1-82c9-ab37601c12f2) talking about it is not possible in EF 4.x to get the **SSpace** items (and thus the table names) by default there is no public APIs yet for those actions.

But i tried to make some tests on this, and i was able to get the table name from **DbContext** at runtime using debugger

this syntax is generated by Visual Studio

```
((System.Data.Entity.DbContext)(context)).System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace._itemsSSpace
```

I made some modifications to make it available in code, and yield to this

```
var objContext = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
var metaData = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var items = metaData.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace);
```

although it follow the same targets, the `items` threw exception `The space 'SSpace' has no associated collection.`

- First: why this error occur.
- Second: is there any way to get this SSpcae items, or the table name??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Database Table Name from Entity Framework MetaData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895455/get-database-table-name-from-entity-framework-metadata)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way at run-time.

```
        public static List<string> GetTableNames()
    {
        List<string> tableNameList = new List<string>();
        // use DBContext to get ObjectContext
        DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
        IObjectContextAdapter adapter = db as IObjectContextAdapter;
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;

        ReadOnlyCollection<EntityType> allTypes = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
        foreach (EntityType item in allTypes)
        {
            // Create full assembly name
            string typeName = "original.poco.namespace." + item.Name;
            Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

            // wrap into a function
            string sql = db.Set(type).ToString();
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"FROM \[dbo\]\.\[(?<table>.*)\] AS");
            Match match = regex.Match(sql);
            tableNameList.Add( match.Groups["table"].Value);
        }

        return tableNameList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because the store collection will not be filled until you do something (perform a query) to make EF require the store collection. But even if you have it, it will do you no good. You can get a list of table names this way, but the mapping to your entities is in the CSSpace item collection, which is completely inaccessible because it uses types internal to the EF runtime. If you have entities A and B, and tables C and D, even if you know you have a straight one-to-one mapping, you cannot find whether A is mapped to C or to D.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using these classes all over the place; should prove helpful.  Works with EF4 or 5.  To get the ObjectContext to pass into the top level EntityNavigationList.List from a DbContext, use ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext.  The simple list of table names will be the FromEntity of each item in EntityNavigationList.List.

```
public class NavigationItem
{
    public string FromEntity { get; set; }
    public string ToEntity { get; set; }
    public RelationshipMultiplicity FromMultiplicity { get; set; }
    public RelationshipMultiplicity ToMultiplicity { get; set; }
    public string ForeignKeyColumn { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryKeyColumn { get; set; }
    public EntitySetBase EntitySet { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Entity type may be "Formula"; entity set may be "Formulae"
    /// </summary>
    public string EntitySetName { get { return EntitySet == null ? string.Empty : EntitySet.Name; } }
}  

public static class EntityNavigationList
{
    private static List<NavigationItem> _navItems;

    public static List<NavigationItem> List( ObjectContext context )
    {
        if ( _navItems == null )
        {
            InitializeNavigationItems( context );
        }
        return _navItems;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a list of all navigation items in the model
    /// </summary>
    private static void InitializeNavigationItems( ObjectContext context )
    {
        var entityMetadata = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems( DataSpace.CSpace );
        var entitySetMetadata = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer( context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace ).BaseEntitySets;

        var query = from meta in entityMetadata
                      .Where( m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType )
                    from p in ( meta as EntityType ).NavigationProperties
                    let foreignKey = ( p.ToEndMember.DeclaringType as AssociationType ).ReferentialConstraints.FirstOrDefault()
                    let primaryKey = ( meta as EntityType ).KeyMembers
                    select new NavigationItem
                    {
                        FromEntity = p.FromEndMember.Name,
                        ToEntity = p.ToEndMember.Name,
                        FromMultiplicity = p.FromEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity,
                        ToMultiplicity = p.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity,
                        ForeignKeyColumn = foreignKey == null ? string.Empty : foreignKey.ToProperties.First().ToString(),
                        PrimaryKeyColumn = primaryKey == null ? string.Empty : primaryKey.First().Name,
                        /// We need the corresponding entity set so we can get it's name (formula belongs to entity set "formulae")
                        EntitySet = ( from moMeta in entitySetMetadata
                                      where moMeta.ElementType.Name == p.FromEndMember.Name
                                      select moMeta ).FirstOrDefault()
                    };

        _navItems = query.ToList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code developed today for the Northwind sample DB from Microsoft that demonstrates how to get the list of tables from an entity data model and then display the top x rows from the table selected in a DataGridView.

To run the code below as is:

1. Create a Windows forms app
2. Add an entity data model for the Northwind DB, call it 'NorthwindModel'
3. Add two combo boxes and a datagridview (tablesComboBox, topXComboBox and dataGridViewForOutput)
4. Add items to the topXComboBox (All, Top 5, Top 10, etc (Must be multiple of 5 for code to work)
5. Change the form name to mainForm
6. Highlight all code in the form file and replace with the following

```
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace EntityFrameworkBrowser
    {
        public partial class mainForm : Form
        {

            public mainForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Type type = typeof(NorthwindModelEntities);
                var query = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetMethod.ToString().ToLower().Contains(".dbset")).Select(m => m.Name);
                tablesComboBox.DataSource = query.ToList();
                topXComboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
            }

            private async void BindTableData()
            {
                // Ensure the form has been initialised
                if (topXComboBox.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1))
                {
                    return;
                }
                // Get the DB context 
                NorthwindModelEntities dbContext = new NorthwindModelEntities();
                // Get a reference to the type of the model
                Type type = typeof(NorthwindModelEntities);
                // Get the table name selected by the user in the combo box
                string tableName = tablesComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                // Get a reference to the DbSet from the model
                var prop = type.GetProperty(tableName);
                // Get a reference to the getter for the DbSet
                MethodInfo get = prop.GetMethod;
                // Invoke the getter for the DbSet 
                object tableContent = get.Invoke(dbContext, null);
                // Create a query that will return all records from the selected table
                IQueryable query = (IQueryable)tableContent;
                // Find out how many records the user has requested, All, Top5, Top 10, etc
                int count = topXComboBox.SelectedIndex * 5;
                // If a value other than all (selected index 0) has been selected the query needs to be refactored
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    // Get the element type for the DbSet from the entity data model
                    Type returnType = query.ElementType;
                    // Get a reference to the 'Take' extension method 
                    MethodInfo takeMethod = (MethodInfo)typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Take");
                    // Make a generic version of the 'Take' method
                    MethodInfo m = takeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(returnType);
                    // Refactor the query to take the top X records based on the user combo box selection
                    query = (IQueryable)m.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, count });
                }
                // Execute the query and bind the results to the data grid view
                dataGridViewForOutput.DataSource = await query.ToListAsync();
            }

            private void tablesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BindTableData();
            }

            private void topXComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BindTableData();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully the comments should explain what is going on, you wouldn't guess it.

Hope it helps someone as it took some working out

:0)