# How to find out the table name of an entity class type in Table-Per-Hierarchy?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

I was found following code to find out the table name of an entity given entity class type using `GetTableName` method. But `GetEntitySet` method fails, because in TPH the table name, and therefore seemingly EntitySetBase is different than the subtype. It throws an exception with message `"Entity type not found in GetTableName"`, from the `throw` statement in line 15.

If I have a base class `A` and a derived class `B`, how can I find out which EntitySetBase object does type B correspond to? (It should give me EntitySetBase related to A, so that I can find out records are in table `[dbo].[As]`.)

```
    private static Dictionary<Type, EntitySetBase> _mappingCache =
       new Dictionary<Type, EntitySetBase>();

    private EntitySetBase GetEntitySet(Type type) {
        if (!_mappingCache.ContainsKey(type)) {
            ObjectContext octx = ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext;
            string typeName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(type).Name;
            var es = octx.MetadataWorkspace
                            .GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
                            .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
                            .SelectMany(c => c.BaseEntitySets
                                            .Where(e => e.Name == typeName))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
            if (es == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Entity type not found in GetTableName", typeName);
            _mappingCache.Add(type, es);
        }
        return _mappingCache[type];
    }

    private string GetTableName(Type type) {
        EntitySetBase es = GetEntitySet(type);
        return string.Format("[{0}].[{1}]",
            es.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value,
            es.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value);
    }
```

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18964974/150342

Comment: Yes, actually the above code is from your answer and a related blog post. But the problem here is, it does not work when you provide a type that is down in a hierarchy which is mapped as TPH. It cannot find related `EntitySetBase` object because there is none for class `B`, but only for `A`.

Comment: I also found this library https://entityframework.codeplex.com/documentation, which looked promising and a neat solution. 

    `ctx.Db(entryEntityType).TableName`
But it gave me an error for any call of `Db` extension method (with or without parameters/generic type parameters) and the error message was exactly containing the type `B`. So I thought maybe this special case was not considered in that library.

Comment: Did you look at the other links in that answer? http://romiller.com/2013/09/24/ef-code-first-mapping-between-types-tables/ and http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/

Comment: To put it more specifically, when you watch the result of this expression `var es = octx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace).GetItems<EntityContainer>().SelectMany(c => c.BaseEntitySets.Select(e => e.Name))`, you observe that none of them are derived types, only base types exist there. I cannot find any information related to mapping of subtypes to a table name or to a `BaseEntitySet` object.

Comment: I am now looking into them. Hovewer, I am currently using EF6, but soon will need downgrade to 5 due to lack of support for Oracle (gonna switch to Oracle 10g from Sql Server 2012).

Comment: Although there is no inheritance in http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/ it seems it might work. Again there is the wall of EF6. :-/