# Entity framework and sql identity issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, uniqueidentifier

I need to reset my ID (identity) of my table because each time I make an update, I have to begin my IDs on 1 due to they increase it into more than 60 000 records each time. How can I do this?

```
using (DailyContext context= DailyContext.Create())
{
    //cleaning old prices
    foreach (var price in context.Prices)
    {
        context.DeleteObject(price);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();


    for (int i = 0; i < newElements.Total; i++)
    {
        var newPrice = new Price()
        {

            Date = newElements.From.AddDays(i),
            PriceFrom = newElements.Price,
            TotalNights = newElements.TotalNights,
            Profit = newElements.Profit
        };
        context.AddToPrices(newPrice);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: DailyContext is type global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext

Comment: If you find you are needing to reset your Identity values perhaps you should look in to if your table needs a design change. Perhaps you should use a `bigint` or drop identity entirely and use `uniqueidentifer` with a `newsequentialid()` default value.

Comment: Yeah, that smells, but if you must: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155856/how-to-reseed-localdb-table-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through and deleting the prices individually in EF just use `ExecuteSqlCommand` to `TRUNCATE` the table.

This both empties it (more efficiently than `DELETE`) and resets the `IDENTITY` column value.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the identity you need to do it outside of EF and you must do raw queries. The query you need to run is [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) with the `RESEED` parameter.

```
using (DailyContext context= DailyContext.Create())
{
    //cleaning old prices
    foreach (var price in context.Prices)
    {
        context.DeleteObject(price);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();

    //Reseed the identity to 0.
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT (Prices, RESEED, 0)");
    //Roll the identity forward till it finds the last used number.
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT (Prices, RESEED)");

    for (int i = 0; i < newElements.Total; i++)
    {
        var newPrice = new Price()
        {

            Date = newElements.From.AddDays(i),
            PriceFrom = newElements.Price,
            TotalNights = newElements.TotalNights,
            Profit = newElements.Profit
        };
        context.AddToPrices(newPrice);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

EDIT:

Here is a version that just does it with SqlCommand and has no dependency on Entity Framework.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction("PricesCleanup"))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("", connection, trans))
    {
        //Reseed the identity to 0.
        command.CommandText = "DBCC CHECKIDENT (Prices, RESEED, 0)";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Roll the identity forward till it finds the last used number.
        command.CommandText = "DBCC CHECKIDENT (Prices, RESEED)";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a problem. When you refer   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand that don't work for me Database don't appear, I create the context using reverse creation of an edmx file from a table of my database. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know why you don't have a `Database` property, but all that really matters is you just run those two lines of SQL. I added a version that just uses SqlCommand.