# Get the Entities names from Wcf Data Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service on server using Entity Framework 5. on my client I have a WinForm Application that will display data from the data service. I added a Service Reference using the .svc file and everything is working greet.
Now, I need a list of all the entity names(table names) that are part of my edmx model. is there a way to do that using the DataServiceContext object in my client application? is there any "built-in" way of getting that?

Edit:
I don't want to get the names directly from the edmx. i want to do it with the 
DataServiceContext. I want to see the entities that the data service is mapping.

```
        NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities(newUri("https://mywebsite.net/service.svc"));
```

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Database Table Name from Entity Framework MetaData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895455/get-database-table-name-from-entity-framework-metadata)

Comment: i think it refers to EDMX that on the same solution. not with wcf data service.