# EF string of random numbers in GetType().Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I am reading entity name from ChangeTracker.Entries().GetType().Name but it has string of random numbers attached to entity name. Is there a way to get correct entity/table name.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Database Table Name from Entity Framework MetaData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895455/get-database-table-name-from-entity-framework-metadata)

Comment: did quick look at that but didn't see easy way to do it (& didn't bother reading long code). have found simple way to get it and have added it here just in case if somebody needs it

Answer (score 2):

found solution

ObjectContext.GetObjectType(change.Entity.GetType()).Name